# How to authenticate a user when embedding Google Calendar in external website without making the calendar public

Tags: php, authentication, google-calendar-api, private

I'm looking for the best way to authenticate a user and give him access to a Google calendar embedded in an external website; I cannot share the calendar with the world because it contains private events.
My solution is to use the same authentication for consuming Google APIs (please my code below); once the user logs in Google account (part of the authentication), and accept permissions, he is basically logged in to Google and he can see the (private) events in the Google Calendar.

Is there a better way to give the user access to the embedded Google calendar (without sharing the calendar with the world)?

My code:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Calendar Project");

$client->setClientId('XXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('XXX');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXX');
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) 
{
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    ?><iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=emailhere%40gmail.com&ctz=America/Los_Angeles" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><?php
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "Access the calendar <a class='login' href='$authUrl'>here</a>";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You will have to make it have shared access with few GMail accounts, so that they can login and view the calendar.. This option is available under Calendar settings.